# Jenkins project display name versus project name configuration

Tags: user-interface, jenkins

How do I configure a Jenkins project to have a friendly name? Meaning a name where spaces and special characters may be allowed and not tied to the projet name that is used for the workspace directory...

I already done this in the past but I can't find out where can I edit the "display name" of a projet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below -
Job -> Configure -> Advanced Project Options -> Display Name

[image]

As per its help -

```
If set, the optional display name is shown for the project throughout the Jenkins web GUI. As it is for display purposes only, the display name is not required to be unique amongst projects.
If the display name is not set, the Jenkins web GUI will default to showing the project name.
```